# JavaCPP fails at function disambiguation

Tags: java, c++, javacpp

I am implementing a Java wrapper for a C++ project using [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp). I have defined mappings for all custom types, but I'm struggling with a call to the [`std::sort_heap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap) function that takes a function as an argument.

This is the function call in the C++ code:

```
std::sort_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comparePairs);
```

`comparePairs` is declared like this in this file:

```
bool comparePairs(
  const std::pair<real, int32_t>& l,
  const std::pair<real, int32_t>& r) {
    return l.first > r.first;
}
```

When I try to run this with JavaCPP (using the [JavaCPP Maven plugin](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/wiki/Maven)), I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘pop_heap(std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::pair<float, int> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), comparePairs);
                                                       ^
```

Update: the problem seems to be due to the fact that another `compairePairs()` with a slightly different signature function is declared in another file. The C++ compiler disambiguates them fine, considering that each `compairePairs()` function is called only within the same file. However, JavaCPP seems to fail at that disambiguation somehow.

This is how the other type mappings are declared:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Info;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.InfoMap;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.InfoMapper;
[...]

@Properties(value = @Platform(include = {[...]}), target = "[...]")
public class Wrapper implements InfoMapper {
  public void map(InfoMap infoMap) {
    infoMap.put(new Info("std::vector<std::string>").pointerTypes("StringVector").define())
       // more put calls here
       ;
  }
}
```

Question is thus: why does JavaCPP fail to disambiguate overloaded functions, and how can I fix it?

Note: the C++ code is a third party project, so changing the C++ code is not an option.

Update: the issues appears to be due to the `compairPairs()` function being declared twice in the C++ code (in two different files), with different signatures.

Comment: Do you have another comparePairs function with different input parameters? If yes, try to wrap the function with a lambda like in this example: https://godbolt.org/z/YLrGAb

Comment: It does compile in C++ because both `comparePairs` functions are declared in the same file in which they are called respectively. This is about FastText, see [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/40a77442a756ab160ae3465b26322f6e480405d9/src/fasttext.cc#L815) and [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/40a77442a756ab160ae3465b26322f6e480405d9/src/loss.cc#L20).

Comment: Then must be something related to JavaCpp, and I know nothing about it. Sorry, I hope somebody else can help you.

Comment: If this can be worked around with a small patch, I would say that's fine. We can bundle this easily, no need to modify anything upstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comment, wrapping the function call to `comparePairs()` into a lambda function resolves the issue.

See https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/936/commits/cda295f1b5851df0a26a6ac2ab04230fb864a89d